# Azure Cache Preview - Premature expiry

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

We're running Azure Cache (Preview) in co-located mode and we've been noticing that sometimes items can not be found in the cache or expires prematurely.

To understand my problem better have a look at the following output from our logs

```
2012-07-26 03:14:15,093 [13] DEBUG XXX.CacheBase - Update: XXX-CacheKey-XXX | Abs Exp: 07/26/2012 04:15:15 +00:00 | Sli Exp: 00:00:00
2012-07-26 03:14:17,452 [22] DEBUG XXX.CacheBase - PessimisticFetch - XXX-CacheKey-XXX
2012-07-26 03:24:32,229 [23] DEBUG XXX.CacheBase - PessimisticFetch - XXX-CacheKey-XXX
2012-07-26 03:24:32,245 [23] DEBUG XXX.SomeClass - Item not found in cache: XXX-CacheKey-XXX
```

Explination:

1. Line 1: Insert into cache with absolute expiry, notice the absolute ex
2. Line 2: Minute or so later a fetch - A OK
3. Line 3: 10 Minute's or so later a fetch - Not Found
4. Line 4: Item reported not found in cache

In short we use GetAndLock / PutAndLock to store these specific items. These items have an absolute expiry (1 Hour) but anything from 5 -- 10 minutes later the item is not in the cache any more.

What is more disturbing on my CacheItemPolicy I've setup a remove notification, but this never gets triggerd

```
//---
cacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback = ItemRemoved;
//---    

static void ItemRemoved(CacheEntryRemovedArguments args)
{
    _log.DebugFormat("Item evicted from cache: {0}. Reason: {1}", args.CacheItem.Key, args.RemovedReason);
}
```

I also attached screen shot of our cache setup 
See Image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ORQQ.jpg

I've ran out of ideas what it could be... any leads explanations, WTF's would is appreciated :)

Comment: This could just be a typo, but I noticed two separate keys are referenced in your log - XXX-CacheKey-XXX and XXX-Cache-XXX. Is that on purpose, or a typo?  Also, why not use the Sliding expiration - according to the log, you're using absolute expiration...

Comment: Yeah just a typo, I'm just hiding my original key... I'll be honest what I'm caching is OAuth tokens, so in this case I want them to absolute expire, as you have X amount of seconds to use the access token.

Obviously we do have the DB as secondary storage, but ideally the premature expiration should not occur :)